# Поверхностное копирование объекта с помощью Object.assign

Tags: javascript, объекты, копирование

```
function shallowCopy(obj) {
  // Как с помощью метода Object.assign создать функцию shallowCopy? 
  // На вход она должна принимать объект, а возвращать — поверхностную
  // копию этого объекта.
}
    
const myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
};
    
const myObjCopy = shallowCopy(myObj);
    
console.log(myObjCopy === myObj); // false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поверхностное копирование:

```js
const myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

const newObj = { ...myObj }

console.log(myObj === newObj)
// false
```

```js
const myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

const newObj = Object.assign({}, myObj)

console.log(myObj === newObj)
// false
```

Функция:

```js
const myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

function shallowCopy(obj) {
  return Object.assign({}, obj)
  // или
  // return { ...obj }
}

const newObj = shallowCopy(myObj)

console.log(newObj)
// {
//  "one": 1,
//  "two": 2,
//  "three": 3
// }

console.log(myObj === newObj)
// false
```

Глубокое копирование:

(только для "простых случаев", см. ниже)

```js
const myObj = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
}

const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj))

console.log(myObj === newObj)
// false
```

(важно)

Данный метод не подойдет если в Вашем объекте присутствует структуры данных `Map`, `Set`, классы типа `Date`, `Infinity`, `undefined`, функции, типизированные массивы...

```js
const myObj = {
  boolean: true,
  string: "строка",
  number: 12345,
  nul: null,
  undfd: undefined,
  inf: Infinity,
  date: new Date(),
  func: () => console.log("функция")
}

const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj))

console.log(newObj)
// {
//  "boolean": true,
//  "string": "строка",
//  "number": 12345,
//  "nul": null,
//  "inf": null,
//  "date": "2020-08-28T22:06:14.982Z"
// }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Как ответ связан с вопросом?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObj))` - не создает **поверхностную** копию, плюс может упасть, в зависимости от переданного объекта

Comment: пункт равны - не делает копию

Comment: что вообще значат равны/не равны/функция ? Как это относится к вопросу: как сделать копию?